# Firebase Flutter Get/Compare document id uppercase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I have an issue.
I save the user ID uppercased, when I want to make a validation I try to get the user documents where the ID = Firebase Doc ID but in my testes I see that Firebase is returning null = don't match the document id.

Any workaround?

Firebase Document ID:

```
182nXEGxmfcOXaxo9jhfVkxCpIq1
```

1st line is the searched ID:

```
I/flutter (19284): INVITE CODE :: 182NXEGXMFCOXAXO9JHFVKXCPIQ1
```

This is when I try to get the Firebase Document ID:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(inviteCode).get()

print("DATA CHECK: "+ userDoc.data.toString());
I/flutter (19284): DATA CHECK: null
```

**EDIT (I get the docID from other widget, ID exist but returns null on the future):**

`String docId = doc['userId'];
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: Firestore.instance.collection('u').document(docId).get(),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make sure the document ID is exactly correct before passing it to Firestore.  Firestore doesn't have any case-insensitive comparison operations.

Comment: Check my edit, this issue don't happen when I add the id with right case (exactly like firebase)

Comment: After many tests yes, Firebase fault or Dart, the uppercase don't work. Only work if the case matches the one in Firebase.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my answer is saying.  They have to be exactly the same.  I don't know why anyone would downvote this.